# MaterialAnimatedSwitch saving state

Tags: java, android

In android studio, I am attempting to create a switch that the user can flip that indicated he or she is online.the switch works fine, however any time the orientation changes or the user exits the app, the switch defaults and is therefore no longer online. I have tried experimenting with onSaveInstanceState but do not know how to pass a variable to indicate the button has been flipped and should stay flipped during different intents and exiting out of the app. Currently, my code for the button is:

```
 location_switch = (MaterialAnimatedSwitch)findViewById(R.id.location_switch);
        location_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MaterialAnimatedSwitch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();
                    startLocationUpdates();
                    displayLocation();
                    Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are online", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{

                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
                    stopLocationUpdates();
                    mCurrent.remove();
                    mMap.clear();
                    handler.removeCallbacks(drawPathRunnable);
                    Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are offline", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Is there anyway I could save all the information from this intent entirely? If not, I would just like to keep the button on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onCreate` after `setContentView` do this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

location_switch = (MaterialAnimatedSwitch)findViewById(R.id.location_switch);

// Set the status of the switch from shared preferences
location_switch.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("location_switch_state", false));

location_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MaterialAnimatedSwitch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(boolean isChecked) {

        // Save the switch status in shared preferences
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("location_switch_state", isChecked);
        editor.apply();

        if(isChecked){
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();
            startLocationUpdates();
            displayLocation();
            Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are online", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
            stopLocationUpdates();
            mCurrent.remove();
            mMap.clear();
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawPathRunnable);
            Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are offline", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```